# Get-WMIObject Invalid query querying a list a servers

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to run a powershell query against a list of servers in an OU in ADUC. Here's the code:

```
$Serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase ("OU=Member Servers, OU=KDHR, OU=RC South, DC=afghan, DC=swa, DC=ds, DC=army, DC=mil") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
$Server
$LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem $Server | Select -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime

Write-Host "$LastBootUpTime"
```

}
And this is the output I'm getting:

```
ServerName                                                                                                                                     
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select ServerName from Win32_OperatingSystem"
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\LastReboot.ps1:6 char:19
+ $LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem $Server | Select -Exp Last ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

It looks like it is trying to pass "Name=SameServerName" into my Get-WMIObject cmdlet, as opposed to just "SameServerName". I output the server name ahead of time just to see what $Server is holding and it seems to come out right, but when it goes in the cmdlet, it seems to add the "Name=" in there. Any idea why?

EDIT: I just realized that I left out the parameter "-ComputerName" in my GetWmiObject cmdlet. So now that line looks like this:

```
$LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server | Select -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime
```

It's working now, which is weird because before, I was getting an "RPC is unavailable" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

foreach ($Server in (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase ("OU=EachOUupFromTheServerOU, DC=DomainNameSplitUpByEachDotInTheDomain"))
{

```
 $Servername = $Server.name

 $LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $Servername | Select -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime

 Write-Output $LastBootUpTime
```

}

Keep in mind that this will run slow as you are querying AD directly.  Best practice would be to have the list of server names already listed in a text or csv file.

Comment: Well, that indeed changed what was getting put into the cmdlet, but it still gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original is modified, this answer is rewritten.

Why this is wretched:

```
PS D:\Scripts> Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem {name=localhost}

Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select name=localhost from 
Win32_OperatingSystem"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem {name=localhost}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Management 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Let's assume a slight clue on Windows Management Instrumentation but no idea on the rest. What are the 'Win32_OperatingSystem' and '{name=localhost}' doing there:

```
Get-Help -Name 'Get-WmiObject' -Online
```

Basically, check documentation first. Wisecracks' shorter variant is:

```
help gwmi
```

But that illustrates the point: be strict to parameters and their values. Know that parameters without a position, can be valued by naming them. In general, positional parameters accept things like 'help gwmi', but the erring Get-WmiObject-cmdlet didn't worked that way very well. As are the majority of cmdlets with cheesy features: be specific in what you want.

A l w a y s command PowerShell by stating parameters, unless you're  indisputably sure of all positions. Heck, -ComputerName isn't even the second positional parameter for this cmdlet. Class is the first, that's correct, but the rest is, well stated in the error. Hence, an error in the category of 'InvalidArgument', so dust your shell of and try again:

```
PS D:\Scripts> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName {name=localhost}
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x800706BA)
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName {name=localh ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
   .GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Leaving out the details, do you think a machine with a name similar to '{e/ndp%01n!}' exists on the network? Nor does '{localhost}', thus it should be 'localhost', a data type as simple as possible.

Speaking of, in the unedited question, that articulated the first issue. Presenting a value of "...{name=ServerName}..." to a parameter which requires a primitive 'ServerName', is invalid, thus it'll break. That stuff was iterated from a [hash table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx). Why? Because the output of Get-ADComputer, like almost all other PowerShell cmdlets, is a combination of various data structures. There's still a difference in selecting a specific property from an object, and expanding that specific property to a new object.

Comment: I saw the hashtable, but I was trying to figure out why that may be happening, specifically because I put "Select-Object Name" at the end.

Comment: That's just formatting. See the .ps1xml files in the PowerShell folder for details (but save that for later ;)

Try Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' instead of Select-Object -Property 'Name'

Comment: That did indeed changed the way input was being put into cmdlet, so that's interesting. The error is still the same though.

Comment: Really? I doubt it. What's the InvocationInfo now you've drilled down the variable to a string type? Or more concrete: whats the invalid query now?

Comment: I didn't get the notification that you had updated your answer, but yes, I see the difference between selecting ExpandProperty versus just selecting what you think the property is. ComputerName isn't even a positional parameter at all, as I understand the help on it, right? So, if I see something like a hash table where I wasn't expecting one, it probably means I didn't select my properties correctly. It was weird because I was writing out $Server to the screen and it worked fine at one point and not at another. I don't remember where now though. Yeah, I'm kinda new to Powershell.